# access auth for boot method to use variable in master blade

Tags: laravel

When I am trying to access `Auth::user()->id;`.  its give me

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

i am trying to access it in boot method for `App\Providers`

```
namespace App\Providers;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
        public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);


        $value = Auth::user()->id;  
        view()->composer('layouts.member', function ($view) use ($value)           {
            $view->with('value', $value);
        });

    }
   }
```

I am going to make builder-bulder for query to use variable into master layouts blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Auth` facade in the AppServiceProvider as the application is not fully booted yet.

Also, you will get the same error if there is no authenticated user. So it's better to wrap it in an `optional` method to avoid this error. In this case the value will be `null`.

However, you can use it inside the closure if you want that's what you want.

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);


    view()->composer('layouts.member', function ($view) {

        $value = optional(Auth::user())->id;  
        $view->with('value', $value);
    });

}
```

Comment: `$value = optional(Auth::user())->id;` this is not giving any result yet, already logged... nothing is outcome yes. only no error.

Comment: How do you use the `$value` in your balde?

Comment: this should be print ID but, nothing is in view.

Comment: {{$value}} this is in my blade...  if i do this  $value = "hi";  then blade give me result hi

Comment: under this line`$value = optional(Auth::user())->id` put `dd($value);` for testing. What do you get?